# How to use v-model for both form and populate the dropdown

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to do two tasks using a v-select which is having dynamic items to load.

**1. want to bind item-text with form to insert.**

**2. want to get item-id while select the option.**

My code :

```
<v-select
        :items="titles"
        item-text="ocmtitle"
        item-value="id"
        v-model="ocmform.title"
        label="Ocm Title"
        @change="getOcmsubtitles()"
        outline
        ></v-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `multi-select` for `v-model` the element. Here is an example.

```js
new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  data: {
    value: '',
    options: [{
        name: 'Vue.js',
        language: 'JavaScript'
      },
      {
        name: 'Rails',
        language: 'Ruby'
      },
      {
        name: 'Sinatra',
        language: 'Ruby'
      },
      {
        name: 'Laravel',
        language: 'PHP',
        $isDisabled: true
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {}
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Avenir', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" placeholder="Pick some" label="name" track-by="name" id="example">
  </multiselect>
  <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value  }}</code></pre>
</div>
```